# Boolean variable set to true even after if-else statement

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean

I am writing a program for school to read a file of baby names from the SSA and return statistics on the number of names for a given year.

I have trouble in outputting a false `found` boolean, which would allow to me print that the given name was not found.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class BabyNames{
    public static void main(String []args)
    throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        File file = new File ("babynames.txt");        
        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        int amount = 0;
        System.out.print("Name? ");
        String s1 = console.next();
        boolean found = true;

        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = input.nextLine();
            Scanner lineScan = new Scanner(line);
            String name  = lineScan.next();

            if(name.equals(s1)){
                found = true;

                for(int i = 1; i<= 11; i++) {
                    amount = lineScan.nextInt();
                    int k = amount / 20;                    
                    System.out.print((i * 10) + 1890 + ": ");
                    for(int r = 1; r <= k; r++) {
                        System.out.print("*");                        
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }

            } else {
                found = false;
            }           
        }
        if(found = false){ //it never turns back into false
            System.out.println(s1 + " is not found.");
        }
        input.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Even after that, the logic is severely flawed. Your check for the value of found only checks the last input line - its value is ignored for all other input lines.

Comment: Getting acquainted with your IDE's debugger should help significantly. You would have seen that `found` becomes `false` every time ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if(found = false){` **assigns** `false` to `found` and then tests the result (which will always be `false`). The equality operator is `==`, not `=`. `=` is always *assignment*.

But with boolean variables, you basically never want `==` or `!=`. Just test the variable itself:

```
if (!found) {
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check your last `if`. You probably meant this:

```
if(found == false){ //it never turns back into false
    System.out.println(s1 + " is not found.");
}
```

but to prevent this kind of mistake in the future, you should do this:

```
if(!found){ //reads "if not found"
    System.out.println(s1 + " is not found.");
}
```

Comment: And that is the reason you should never compare a boolean to true or false.

Comment: So consider doing if(!found).